# Как удалить последний символ из виджета Text() tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как удалить последний символ в строке ввода `Expression` при нажатии кнопки `Clear_symbol`? Попробовал указать индекс словом `END`, но это не дало результата

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Python')
root.geometry('158x55')
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)


def Clear_symbol_Act():
    Expression.delete(END)
    
        
First_line = Frame(root, background='olivedrab')    



Clear_symbol = Button(First_line, text = "←", background = "#555", 
                      foreground = "white",font = "25", width = 3, 
                      height = 1, command = Clear_symbol_Act)

Expression = Text(First_line, background = "silver", foreground = "black",
                  width = 17, height=3)



Clear_symbol.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)  
Expression.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2) 

First_line.pack(anchor = W)  



root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**delete** ожидает два индекса: начало и конец удаляемой строки (конец удаляемой строки можно не указывать - будет удален один символ).
**END** указывает на позицию за символом новой строки (добавляется автоматически), **"end-1c"** на позицию перед ним, а **"end-2c"** на позицию перед последним символом.

```
Expression.delete("end-2c")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!

Answer (score 2):

Встроенных вариантов вроде как нет, так что можно сделать так:

1. Получаем текущий текст и удаляем 2 последних символа. Именно 2, потому что самый последний символ это - `\n` - символ переноса строки.
2. Очищаем строку полностью и добавляем в нее текст без последнего символа.

**Код:**

```
def Clear_symbol_Act():
    text = Expression.get(1.0, END)[:-2]
    Expression.delete(1.0, END)
    Expression.insert(END, text)
```

Comment: Спасибо за предложенный вариант, возник вопрос, это решение можно назвать костылем? Или это все же просто элегантное решение?)

Comment: Не, как оказалось, это все таки костыль)
Так как имеется прямое решение задачи, в ответе @Spatz