# По какой причине возникает ошибка _tkinter.TclError: bad entry index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Все работало адекватно, последний символ строки ввода `entry`, удалялся когда я нажимал на клавишу `←`, после неизвестно что произошло и вылезла вот такая ошибка, как исправить, что она вообще значит? `неверный индекс записи "end-2c`, а до этого почему был верным? Что изменилось что он стал не верным? Может увидет кто нибудь, я явно что то упускаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код программы:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

# Создания кона приложения
root = Tk()
# Название окна
root.title('Python')
# Размеры окна
root.geometry('205x298')
# Запрет пользователя на изменение рамеров окна
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)




def Calculator():
    while True:
        term = Expression.get("1.0", END)
        term = term[0:-1]
        long_term = len(term)
                
        # Все индексы символов введеных пользователем
        index = []
            
        # Проводим проверку ввода пользователя
        if long_term > 0:
            # Получаем индекс каждого введеного пользователем символа
            while long_term > 0:
                long_term = long_term - 1
                index.insert(0,long_term)
        elif long_term == 0: 
            break
            
        # Все элементы строки введеной пользователем
        term_list = [term[i] for i in index]
        
        # Выход из функции если в поле ввода нет арифметических знаков 
        if set(["+" ,"-" ,"*" ,"/"]).isdisjoint(term_list) == True:
            print('Не найденно арифметическое действие!')
            Expression.delete("1.0", END)
            break
                    
        return term_list
        break


def Arithmetic_action_Plus():
    term = Decision.get()
    Expression.insert(END, term)
    Expression.insert(END, ' ' + '+' + ' ')
    Decision.delete(0, END)

def Plus_Act():
    Arithmetic_action_Plus()
    Calculator()

    
def Arithmetic_action_Minus():
    term = Decision.get()
    Expression.insert(END, term)
    Expression.insert(END, ' ' + '-' + ' ')
    Decision.delete(0, END)
def Minus_Act():
    Arithmetic_action_Minus()
    Calculator()


def Arithmetic_action_Mult():
    term = Decision.get()
    Expression.insert(END, term)
    Expression.insert(END, ' ' + '*' + ' ')
    Decision.delete(0, END)
def Mult_Act():
    Arithmetic_action_Mult()
    Calculator()
        

def Clear_fields_Act():
    Expression.delete("1.0", END)
    Decision.delete(0, END)


def Arithmetic_action_Division():
    term = Decision.get()
    Expression.insert(END, term)
    Expression.insert(END, ' ' + '/' + ' ')
    Decision.delete(0, END)
def Division_Act():
    Arithmetic_action_Division()
    Calculator()
            

def Equally_Act():
    while True:
        term = Decision.get()
        Expression.insert(END, term)
        term_list = Calculator()
        
        # Выход из функции если поле ввода пусто
        if term_list == None:
            break
            
        # Список значений ариф.знаков
        variable_arithmetic = []
        # Список чисел и ариф.знаков строки ввода
        Input_line_numbers = []
        # Список индексов списка чисел и ариф.знаков
        index_arithmetic = []
        
        # Создание списка с конкатенированными числами и ариф.знаками
        for n in term_list.copy():
            if n in ("+", "-", "*", "/"):
                #Узнаем индекс ариф.знака
                index = term_list.index(n)
                #Делаем вырезку в отдельный список от первого знака и до знака ариф.
                Input_line_numbers.append(''.join(term_list[0:index]))
                #Удоляем часть списка от первого знака и до знака арифметики
                del term_list[0:index]
                #Вырезаем в отдельный список сам знак арифметики
                Input_line_numbers.append(''.join(term_list[0]))--
                #Удоляем знак арифметики
                del term_list[0]
        
        
        #Вызераем в отдельный список последнее число
        Input_line_numbers.append(''.join(term_list[0:]))   
        #Удоляем последнее число из списка
        del term_list[0:]       
            
        for symbol in Input_line_numbers.copy():
            if symbol in ("+"):
                num1 = ''.join(Input_line_numbers[0:1])
                num2 = ''.join(Input_line_numbers[2:3])
                if not set(".").isdisjoint(num1) == True or\
                   not set(".").isdisjoint(num2) == True:
                    result = float(num1) + float(num2)
                    result = round(result, 1)
                    result = str(result)
                else:
                    try:
                        result = int(num1) + int(num2)
                    except ValueError:
                        print('\n\n   Нет числа после ариф.действия!')
                        return 'break'
                    
                    result = round(result)
                    result = str(result)
                
                del Input_line_numbers[0:3]
                Input_line_numbers.insert(0,result)
            
            if symbol in ("-"):
                num1 = ''.join(Input_line_numbers[0:1])
                num2 = ''.join(Input_line_numbers[2:3])
                if not set(".").isdisjoint(num1) == True or\
                   not set(".").isdisjoint(num2) == True:
                    result = float(num1) - float(num2)
                    result = round(result, 1)
                    result = str(result)
                else:
                    try:
                        result = int(num1) - int(num2)
                    except ValueError:
                        print('\n\n   Нет числа после ариф.действия!')
                        return 'break'
                    result = round(result)
                    result = str(result)
                
                del Input_line_numbers[0:3]
                Input_line_numbers.insert(0,result)
            
            if symbol in ("*"):
                num1 = ''.join(Input_line_numbers[0:1])
                num2 = ''.join(Input_line_numbers[2:3])
                if not set(".").isdisjoint(num1) == True or\
                   not set(".").isdisjoint(num2) == True:
                    result = float(num1) * float(num2)
                    result = round(result, 2)
                    result = str(result)
                else:
                    try:
                        result = int(num1) * int(num2)
                    except ValueError:
                        print('\n\n   Нет числа после ариф.действия!')
                        return 'break'
                    
                    result = round(result)
                    result = str(result)
                del Input_line_numbers[0:3]
                Input_line_numbers.insert(0,result)
                
            if symbol in ("/"):
                num1 = ''.join(Input_line_numbers[0:1])
                num2 = ''.join(Input_line_numbers[2:3])
                if not set(".").isdisjoint(num1) == True or\
                   not set(".").isdisjoint(num2) == True:
                    result = float(num1) / float(num2)
                    result = str(result)
                else:
                    try:
                        result = int(num1) // int(num2)
                    except ValueError:
                        print('\n\n   Нет числа после ариф.действия!')
                        return 'break'
                    result = round(result)
                    result = str(result)
                
                del Input_line_numbers[0:3]
                Input_line_numbers.insert(0,result)
        
        Decision.delete(0, END)
        Decision.insert(END, result)
        Expression.delete("1.0", END)
        break





#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Создаем фреймы
Expression_line = Frame(root, background='olivedrab',  # Выражение 
                        width = 205, height = 44)     
Decision_line = Frame(root, background='olivedrab',    # Решение
                      width = 205, height = 33)      
First_line = Frame(root, background='olivedrab',       # 7 8 9 +    
                   width = 205, height = 44)         
Second_line = Frame(root, background='olivedrab',      # 4 5 6 -
                    width = 205, height = 44)         
Third_line = Frame(root, background='olivedrab',       # 1 2 3 *
                   width = 205, height = 44)          
Fourth_line = Frame(root, background='olivedrab',      # ← 0 c /
                    width = 205, height = 44)         
Fifth_line = Frame(root, background='olivedrab',       #   =   ,
                   width = 205, height = 44)          
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------




#_Выражение_____________________________________________________________________
Expression = Text(Expression_line, background = "gainsboro", font = "Arial 9",
                  foreground = "black", width = 25)
def check_keys(event):
    if event.char.isalpha() or (event.state & 4 and event.keysym == "v"):
        return "break"

Expression.bind("<Key>", check_keys)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#_Решение_______________________________________________________________________
Decision = Entry(Decision_line, background = "gainsboro", 
                 foreground = "black", font = "Arial 13", width = 17)
Decision.bind("<Key>", check_keys)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------



#_7_____________________________________________________________________________
Seven = Button(First_line, text = "7", background = "#444", 
               foreground = "white", font = "Arial 14", width = 3,
               command = lambda: Decision.insert(END, "7"))
#_8_____________________________________________________________________________
Eight = Button(First_line, text = "8", background = "#444", 
               foreground = "white", font = "Arial 14", width = 3,
               command = lambda: Decision.insert(END, "8"))
#_9_____________________________________________________________________________
Nine = Button(First_line, text = "9", background = "#444", 
               foreground = "white", font = "Arial 14", width = 3,
               command = lambda: Decision.insert(END, "9"))
#_+_____________________________________________________________________________
# Создание кнопки +
Plus = Button(First_line,                  # Нахождение во фрейме
              text = "+",                  # Текст кнопки 
              background = "#555",         # Фоновый цвет кнопки
              foreground = "white",        # Цвет текста
              font = "Arial 12",           # Высота шрифта
              width = 3,                   # Высота кнопки
              height = 1,                  # Ширина кнопки
              command = Plus_Act           # Функция кнопки
              )
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------



#_4_____________________________________________________________________________
Four = Button(Second_line, text = "4", background = "#444", 
              foreground = "white", font = "Arial 14", width = 3,
              command = lambda: Decision.insert(END, "4"))
#_5_____________________________________________________________________________
Five = Button(Second_line, text = "5", background = "#444", 
              foreground = "white", font = "Arial 14", width = 3,
              command = lambda: Decision.insert(END, "5"))
#_6_____________________________________________________________________________
Six = Button(Second_line, text = "6", background = "#444", 
              foreground = "white", font = "Arial 14", width = 3,
              command = lambda: Decision.insert(END, "6"))
#_-_____________________________________________________________________________
Minus = Button(Second_line, text = " - ", background = "#555", 
               foreground = "white", font = "Arial 12", width = 3, 
               height = 1, command = Minus_Act) 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------



#_1______________________________________________________________________________
One = Button(Third_line, text = "1", background = "#444", 
             foreground = "white", font = "Arial 14", width = 3,
             command = lambda: Decision.insert(END, "1"))
#_2______________________________________________________________________________
Two = Button(Third_line, text = "2", background = "#444", 
             foreground = "white", font = "Arial 14", width = 3,
             command = lambda: Decision.insert(END, "2"))
#_3______________________________________________________________________________
Three = Button(Third_line, text = "3", background = "#444", 
               foreground = "white", font = "Arial 14", width = 3,
               command = lambda: Decision.insert(END, "3"))
#_*______________________________________________________________________________
Mult = Button(Third_line, text = " * ", background = "#555", 
              foreground = "white", font = "Arial 12", width = 3, 
              command = Mult_Act) 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------



#_←_____________________________________________________________________________
Clear_symbol = Button(Fourth_line, text = "←", background = "#555", 
                      foreground = "white",font = "Arial 14", width = 3,    
                      command = lambda: Decision.delete("end-3c"))
#_0_____________________________________________________________________________
Zero = Button(Fourth_line, text = "0", background = "#444", 
              foreground = "white",font = "Arial 14", width = 3, 
              command = lambda: Decision.insert(END, "0"))
#_с_____________________________________________________________________________
Clear_fields = Button(Fourth_line, text = "с", background = "#555", 
                      foreground = "white", font = "Arial 14", width = 3,  
                      command = Clear_fields_Act)
#_/_____________________________________________________________________________ 
Division = Button(Fourth_line, text = " / ", background = "#555", 
                  foreground = "white", font = "Arial 12", width = 3, 
                  command = Division_Act)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------



#_=_____________________________________________________________________________
Pixel_Virtual = tk.PhotoImage(width = 1)
Equally = Button(Fifth_line, text = "=", background = "#555", 
                 command = Equally_Act, image = Pixel_Virtual, compound = 'c',
                 foreground = "white", font = "Arial 12", width = 147,)
#_,_____________________________________________________________________________
Comma = Button(Fifth_line, text = ".", background = "#555", 
               foreground = "white", font = "Arial 12", width = 3,
               command = lambda: Decision.insert(END, "."))
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------




#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Указываем выравнивание обьекта во фрейме и его отображение в окне
Expression.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)       # Выражение
Decision.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)         # Решение  

Seven.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)            # 7
Eight.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)            # 8
Nine.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)             # 9
Plus.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)             # +

Four.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)             # 4
Five.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)             # 5
Six.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)              # 6
Minus.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)            # -

One.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)              # 1
Two.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)              # 2
Three.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)            # 3
Mult.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)             # *

Clear_symbol.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)     # ←
Zero.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)             # 0
Clear_fields.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)     # c
Division.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)         # /

Equally.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2,
             expand = 1, fill = Y)                     # =
Comma.pack(side = BOTTOM, padx = 2, pady = 2)          # ,
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# Включаем отображение фрейма в окне
Expression_line.pack(anchor = W)                  # N - Север   ↑
Expression_line.pack_propagate(False)             # S - Юг      ↓

Decision_line.pack(anchor = W)                    # W - Запад   ←
Decision_line.pack_propagate(False)               # E - Восток  →

First_line.pack(anchor = W)         
First_line.pack_propagate(False)

Second_line.pack(anchor = W)        
Second_line.pack_propagate(False)

Third_line.pack(anchor = W)         
Third_line.pack_propagate(False)

Fourth_line.pack(anchor = W)        
Fourth_line.pack_propagate(False)

Fifth_line.pack(anchor = W)   
Fifth_line.pack_propagate(False)   
  



# Реализация бесконечного цикла окна (работа окна)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опытным путем определил, что удаление последнего символа через `.delete("end-2c")` (как в примере в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1213388)) работает с объектом класса `Text` (многострочным текстовым полем), но не работает с объектом `Entry` (однострочным текстовым полем) - и это как раз ваш случай:

```
Decision = Entry(Decision_line, background = "gainsboro", 
                 foreground = "black", font = "Arial 13", width = 17)
```

Чтобы удалить последний символ из `Entry`, нужно числом указать индекс символа, начиная с которого нужно удалять. Для этого нужно получить текст из поля, получить его длину, уменьшить на 1 (индекс последнего символа не 1 меньше длины), пример:

```
def delete_last():
    Decision.delete(len(Decision.get())-1)


Button(text="Del", command=delete_last).pack()
```

Еще вариант удаления последнего символа (взято [отсюда](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/ngdkmk/comment/gyyl6dk/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)):

```
def delete_last():
    Decision.delete(Decision.index("end") - 1)


Button(text="Del", command=delete_last).pack()
```

Comment: К сожалению этот вариант не помог, при нажатии на кнопку просто ничего не происходит `Clear_symbol = Button(Fourth_line, text = "←", background = "#555",                                                 foreground = "white",font = "Arial 14", width = 3,                                                                   command = Decision.delete(len(Decision.get())-1))`

Comment: Ошибки не возникает, просто не происходит ничего при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: Сравните с моим ответом, вы лямбду потеряли.

Comment: Черт возьми, видимо засиделся я с этим Python, спасибо большое за ответ и полезную информацию, помогло!)